# How can the current directory be shown in a singularity container on the terminal?

Tags: singularity-container

I'm a new Singularity user. When I run the command `singularity shell my_con.sif`. The terminal only shows:

```
Singularity>
```

For convenience, is there any way to show the current path on the terminal? For example:

```
/home/user/singularity$
```

Thanks.